# Lotus notes: change view selection formula by script

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm trying to change view selection formula by script with this selection formula:

```vb
formula = "SELECT (@Modified = [" & Left(doc1.LastModified,10) & "])  &  form = ["& Cstr(doc1.form(0)) &"]"
```

But when I try to execute it Notes retrive me the following error:

> Notes error: Unknown [KeyWord] for @Function (SELECT (@Modified = [03/02/2015]) & form=[myform])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use quotes for `form` instead of square brackets.
Here is example:

```
formula$ = {SELECT (@Modified = [} & Left(doc1.LastModified,10) & {]) & form = "} & doc1.form(0) & {"}
```

Which generate this string:

```
SELECT (@Modified = [03/02/2015]) & form = "myform"
```

Comment: just as a clarification: Square brackets are used to convert the string to a date, quotes are used for text- values.